# Arguments within methods

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm starting on methods today & I ran into an error that one of my equations in the main method isn't applicable throughout the whole program. It's the fourth line of code & I thought it was typed correctly. Basically, when you input the length & width, you will get the area of a rectangle as the output. Here's the code:

```
double area = areaOfRectangle();
    String YES = "Y";
    String YES2 = "y";
    String NO = "N";
    String NO2 = "n";
    boolean validInput = false;

    System.out.print("Please enter a length: ");
    float length = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter a width: ");
    float width = input.nextInt();

    System.out.printf("Area: %.2d %n", area);

    do{
    System.out.print("Enter more? (Y/N): ");
    String input2 = input.next();
    if(input.hasNextLine()){
        if(input2.equals("Y") || input2.equals("y")){
            System.out.print("Please enter a length: ");
            length = input.nextFloat();
            System.out.print("Please enter a width: ");
            width = input.nextFloat();

            System.out.printf("Area: %.2d %n", area);
        }
        else if(input2.equals("N") || input2.equals("n")){
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}while(!validInput);
}

public static void areaOfRectangle(float length2, float width2){

        length2 = length;
        width2 = width;

        double rectangle = (length2 * width2);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question (what's the error?), but I do have a tip for you. You can simplify your input checks (Y/y/N/n) by automatically converting input to lowercase. Ex: `if(input2.toLowerCase().equals("y"){`

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
 double area = areaOfRectangle();
```

and

```
 public static void areaOfRectangle(float length2, float width2){
```

So you have a method returning `void` (nothing), which compiles since you're not returning anything, but you're trying to assign that nothing to a double. Also, you're not passing the parameters at all. In java, you cannot assign a method to a variable as in a functional language.

You need:

```
public static double areaOfRectangle(float length2, float width2){

    double rectangle = (double)length2 * width2;
    return rectangle;
}
```

And then calculate area when you have the parameters:

```
double area = areaOfRectangle(length,width);
```

Maybe don't do conversions between float and double either, just use doubles throughout.

Comment: I changed it & it is still showing the error message: " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 length cannot be resolved to a variable
 width cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: Have you left the two lines that reference length and width in areaOfRectangle? These lines are wrong and should be removed. Look at the lines of your error message.

Comment: @JohnWalkern so check where you have defined `length` and `width` in `areaOfRectangle(float length2, float width2)`?